# How to get the correct time Using NSDate with components in swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

When i get the components like seconds in:

NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(.Second, fromDate: savedDate, toDate: todayDate, options: []).second

I get the seconds since that date.
But i am trying to get all the components like days and hours it gives me the total in each one of them.

If i get the hours lets say 36h and the days will show one day.

**1** I want it to show 1 day and 12 hours.

**2.** How to start a counter or a timer with these components?

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify all units in the `components` parameter you want to be considered.

```
let components = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components([.Second, .Minute, .Hour, .Day], fromDate: savedDate, toDate: todayDate, options: [])
print(components)
```

Alternatively use `NSDateComponentsFormatter`, it can create a (localized) string. Specify the units to be displayed and the style.

```
let formatter = NSDateComponentsFormatter()
formatter.allowedUnits = [.Day, .Hour, .Minute, .Second ]
formatter.unitsStyle = .Full
let dateString = formatter.stringFromDate(savedDate, toDate: todayDate)!
print(dateString)
```

Regarding your second question let the counter count in seconds and format the seconds for human reading accordingly.